# What does ls -A do?

Tags: linux, shell, ls

What does ls -A do? I have found this shell script and I can't figure out what ls -A does. In the manual it writes that `ls -A == do not list implied . and ..` but I don't understand what it means.

```
dir=./$1
if [[ -z $(ls -A $dir) ]]
```

Comment: It should induce you to read `man ls`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally `ls` doesn't print filenames that start with a dot. With `-a`, it does, but that includes `.` and `..`, which exist in all directories, and hence aren't very interesting. With `-A` it prints everything but those two.

```
$ touch normal .hidden
$ ls
normal
$ ls -a
./  ../  .hidden  normal
$ ls -A
.hidden  normal
```

---

In that if-statement, the command substitution `$( .. )` captures the output of `ls`, and `[[ -z ... ]]` tests if it's the empty string. That is, that there's no files in the directory.

Usually, reading the output of `ls` is not a good idea, if you want to loop over files in the shell, you can just use `*`. Here, it should work, though, except for the fact that if the given directory name contains whitespace (or filename glob characters), they'll be expanded on the command line of `ls`, which may mess up the results.

See:

- https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)